# Scroll a certain amount on single swipe in horizontal scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview

I have a horizontal scroll view with several text views in it. There is an pointer on the top layout and different text views on getting under the pointer trigger their respective fragments. Right now it scrolls freely and you can stop it between the 2 text views. What I want is to scroll a certain amount everytime I swipe left or right which will result in text view being in center of the pointer above.

I put them in relative layout and here is the xml for it

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ic_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"/>

</LinearLayout>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/HorizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ic_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imgLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:paddingLeft="120dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Random Crap1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Random Crap2"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Random Crap3"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Random Crap4"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Random Crap5"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Random Crap6"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Random Crap7"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="70dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>


</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow :

For scrolling Horizontal ScrollView to specific amount use below code :

```
final HorizontalScrollView YourHorizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.YourHorizontalScrollView);

YourHorizontalScrollView.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final TextView YourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
        int scrollTo = 0;
        final int count = ((LinearLayout) YourHorizontalScrollView.getChildAt(0))
                .getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = ((LinearLayout) YourHorizontalScrollView.getChildAt(0))
                    .getChildAt(i);                 
            if (child != yourTextView) {
                scrollTo += child.getWidth();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        YourHorizontalScrollView.scrollTo(scrollTo, 0);
    }

});
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ViewPager instead of horizontal scroll, that works for me for fixed scroll everytime.
fix the height of ViewPager for better experience.
use a custom adapter for ViewPager

```
public class CustomViewPagerImageAdapterPC extends PagerAdapter {

@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return super.getPageWidth(position);
    return 0.4f;
}
```